# Is it possible to create a method in a read only class

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have a public class that is also a read only class. (i.e it has the padlock in the top right hand of the tab. There are members within the class that are invaluable to other parts of the project. The issue I'm having is that the class consists soley of property fields and no methods.

Here is what the class looks like:

```
 public class UserInfo : ADItemInfo
    {
    public UserInfo();
    public string FirstName{ get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeID { get; set; }
    }
```

Both the UserInfo and ADItemInfo classes are read only.

In my Default.Master.cs page I have a method that will use members: `FirstName, LastName, EmployeeID` to process user authentication. Code listed below.

```
private void ProcessUserAuthentication()
        {
            var userInfo = (UserInfo)Session["UserInfo"];
        if (userInfo == null &&
                Page.User != null &&
                Page.User.Identity != null &&
                !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Page.User.Identity.Name))
        {
            userInfo = UserInfo.GetUserInfo(Page.User.Identity.Name); //ERROR HERE READS: abc.UserInfoclass.does not contain a defintion for 'GetUserInfo'
            Session["UserInfo"] = userInfo;
        }
        if (RequireUserAuthentication)
        {
           // nothing in here right now.
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInfo.FirstName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userInfo.LastName))
        {
            uxUserWelcomeLbl.Text = string.Format("Welcome {0} {1} {2}", userInfo.FirstName, userInfo.LastName, userInfo.EmployeeID);
        }
    }
```

I cannot generate a method stub for this class, as of right now and am unsure of which route to take to solve this issue.

Comment: Read only class? You mean the file is read only? And naturally you can't call a method that doesn't exist. So what is the actual issue?

Comment: There's no such thing as a read only class in C#. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I can't fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. Right now you are calling `GetUserInfo` as it were a static method of the `UserInfo` class, but there is no such method, as we can see in the definition of `UserInfo`.

Do you want to put the result of `Page.User.Identity.Name` into the `userInfo` variable? If so, you can just do something similar to this:

```
userInfo.FirstName = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

> it has the padlock in the top right hand of the tab

If I am correct, this indicates that the *file* is read-only, not the class itself. Maybe you are trying to change something in debug mode?

Comment: @user5085862 - Quit saying `readonly class` and `non-readonly class`. Neither of these concepts exist in C#.